# как из базы данных вытащить объект

Tags: java, android

```
Place place = new Place();
```

Ведь так делать нельзя. Но как вытащить этот Place из бд?

Comment: Если вам нужен именно объект в качестве представления данных из БД, то смотрите по теме готовых решений - ORM для андроид. Впорчем вы можете потратить некоторое количество времени на создание собственной ORM, если готовые решения вас не устраивают. Просто так получить данные в виде объекта из БД нельзя, в андроид для этого используется класс `Cursor`

Comment: Почему нельзя? Из вашего вопроса это не следует. Я вполне допускаю, что с некоторыми ORM так даже **можно**, но как я понимаю, класс `Place` ещё не реализован. Поэтому вас скорее интересует совсем другой вопрос -- как написать класс, экземпляры которого можно хранить в БД? (Это не очень технически корректно, но хотя бы понятно) Отредактируйте вопрос, внеся в него более конкретный вопрос и подробности о том, что в этом направлении уже смотрели.

Answer (score 3):

Если [готовые ORM](https://www.google.ru/search?hl=ru&q=ORM%20android%20sqlite) вам по каким то причинам не подходят, тот примерный алгоритм преобразования записи из БД в объект выглядит так:

1. Создаем некоторый класс POJO-объекта - определяем поля для значений, геттеры и сеттеры для чтения и записи этих полей:

   ```
   public Place { 
     private String someValue;

     public String getValue() {
        return someValue;
     }

     public void setValue(String someValue) {
       this.someValue = someValue;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Создаем класс для преобразования выборки из БД в POJO-объект (только преобразование в объект):

   ```
   public DBHelper {

      //имена колонок с нужными данными
      private static final String[] COLUMNS = {"_id", "value"};
      // имя таблицы с значениями
      private static final String[] TABLE = "table_values"; 

      public Place getPlace(int id){

       // Считываем запись из БД по ее ID
       Cursor cursor = database.query(
         TABLE, COLUMNS,
         "_id = ?",
         new String[] { String.valueOf(id) },
         null,
         null,
         null);
       if (cursor != null) cursor.moveToFirst();

       Place place = new Place();
       // записываем в объект значение из колонки номер 1 в БД (отсчет идет с нуля)
       place.setValue(cursor.getString(1)); 
       return place;
      }

   // Другие методы работы с БД - открытие\закрытие подключения
   // Другие GRUD-операции (запись удаление и тд.)
   }
   ```
3. Используем:

   ```
   Place place = new Place();
   DBHelper helper = new DBHelper();

   place = helper.getPlace(5); // получаем запись из БД с ID = 5
   ```

Здесь только минимальная часть для общего понимания необходимых действий, более подробный рабочий пример смотрите, например, [этот туториал](http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/) (хотя аналогичных много в инете)